# Wrap text element labels

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I am writing a python script for batch map production and for every map the script replaces a text label called "Company". sometimes the name is way to long and it extends onto the map and off the map.

I have not been able to find any wrap labeling info on the internet.

So far i have tried manually editing the label in the MXD but there seems to be no wrap text option

Comment: there is a box text option that would define the width of the box and wrap inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Brad](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/98/brad-nesom) said in his [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185490/wrap-text-element-labels/185495#comment279868_185490) above, you can add a text box that allows you to define the width and height of the box, and any text will automatically wrap inside that.

You can find "**Rectangle Text**" from the Text dropdown on your Drawing toolbar

[image: Find Rectangle Text on the Drawing Toolbar]

Add your text box, set your frame to no border (unless of course you want a border around your text), and **set the textbox to the dimensions you require**.  This box can be used by arcpy the same way as any other text element.

[image: Example of different types of text boxes]

The **Title** and **Text** options from the Insert menu will just resize the text if you try to change the size of the textbox, but the **Rectangle Text** box allows you to set dimensions.

**EDIT:** This code snippet is what I used to test:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Company")[0]

if elm.name == "Company":
    elm.text = "This text is far too long for one line and could go off the edge of the page unless the text wraps within the text box!"
```

Comment: So i defined the text dimensions with the recetangle text but now when the text is too long, it just does not show up. it is not wrapping automatically

Comment: that's odd behaviour - I have added the code I used to test.

Comment: it worked! i needed to set the margins to 0 so the text would appear. thanks

Answer (score 3):

@Midavalo has an excellent solution.  I just wanted to add one alternative if you do not want to work with rectangle text boxes.  You can use the built-in [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module to define how you want to wrap the text based on a character count.  This way you do not have to change the type of your text labels.

It is very simple code:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
>>> txt = [elm for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT")][0]
>>> s = 'This is a very long string that we want to wrap.  It looks very bad when there is overlow and it goes off of the page'
>>> import textwrap
>>> txt.text = '\r\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(s, 15))
>>>
```

And the photo:

[image]

And of course you can always insert manual breaks with carriage returns: `'\r\n'`.

Comment: Okay cool I will give this a try.  txt.text = '\r\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(s, 15)) does the 15 refer to the font size?

Comment: I think 15 will be the character limit (it'll wrap so it doesn't pass 15 characters per line)

Comment: No, 15 is the max amount of characters per line.  You can set this to whatever you need.  This number will vary based on your font size.  I'd check out the documentation.  There are also options for breaking long words with hyphens and other things.

Comment: @Midavalo beat me to it :)